# Method getting called after each action on array item

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a method that retrieves a list of tasks and puts them into an array but every time I perform an action on the tasks (i.e. marking them complete) it calls the fetch method again which doubles the tasks in the array. I can't figure out what is causing the method to get called multiple times. Can someone help me?

```
class Firebase {

    func fetchAllTasksInTeam(ref:FIRDatabaseReference, team:String, completion:(tasksArray:[Task])->()) {
        var newTasks = [Task]()
        ref.child("tasks").queryOrderedByChild("team").queryEqualToValue(team).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            for task in snapshot.children {
                let tasks = Task(snapshot: task as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                    newTasks.append(tasks)
                }
                print("fetchAllTasksInTeam called")
                completion(tasksArray: newTasks)
        })
    }
}

class TasksTVC: UITableViewController, TaskCellDelegate {

    var tasks = [Task]() {
        didSet {
            updateTableView()
            convertTime(sectionTimes)
            tableView?.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        fb.fetchCurrentUser(ref, currentUser: currentUser) { (service, position) in
            self.service = service
            self.position = position
        }

        fb.fetchAllTasksInTeam(ref, team: team) { (tasksArray) in
            print("\(tasksArray.count) tasks")
            self.tasks = tasksArray
        }

        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
        }
    }            

    func doneHit(cell:TaskCell) {
        if let ip = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
            let task = tasksInSectionArray[ip.section][ip.row]
            if task.done == false {
                cell._checkBox.setOn(true, animated: true)
                task.done = true
                task.completedBy = user         
            } else {
                cell._checkBox.setOn(false, animated: true)
                task.done = false
                task.completedBy = ""        
            }
            fb.updateTaskDoneBool(ref, task: task)
            fb.updateTaskCompletedBy(ref, task: task)
        }
    }

    func updateTableView() {
        sectionTimes = Set(tasks.map{$0.dueTime}).sort()
        groupTimes()
        if service == "9AM" && position != "Staff" {
             tasksInSectionArray = nineTimes.map{section in tasks.filter{$0.dueTime == section}}
        }
        else if service == "12PM" && position != "Staff" {
             tasksInSectionArray = noonTimes.map{section in tasks.filter{$0.dueTime == section}}
        }
        else if service == "5PM" && position != "Staff" {
             tasksInSectionArray = fiveTimes.map{section in tasks.filter{$0.dueTime == section}}
        }
        else {
            tasksInSectionArray = sectionTimes.map{section in tasks.filter{$0.dueTime == section}}
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what do the `updateTableView()` func?

Comment: updated post with func

Comment: ... You're right, I don't see anything that could be causing it in there. Is `fetchAllTasksInTeam()` being called anywhere else at all? If not, my best answer is "somehow, somewhere, something is destroying and replacing the table, so viewDidLoad() gets called again," for all the good that does you...